# Trying to save contacts with GetResponse api but I am unable to

Tags: php, api, curl, php-curl, getresponse

My task is to authenticate on this api
https://api.getresponse.com/v3/accounts

Then need to save on the following api
https://api.getresponse.com/v3/POST/contacts

data must be in the following format

```
{
"name": "Hemant Maurya",
"email": "xyz@yahoo.com",
"dayOfCycle": "0",
"campaign": {
    "campaignId": "6mzZL"
},
"tags": [
    {
        "tagId": "Xw"
    },
    {
        "tagId": "Nn"
    }
],
"scoring": 25,
"customFieldValues": [
    {
        "customFieldId": "n",
        "value": [
            "white"
        ]
    }
],
"ipAddress": "14.143.38.111"
}
```

Following code can authenticate

```
$url = "https://api.getresponse.com/v3/accounts";
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "X-Auth-Token: api-key 17fbe43cc8a23daaf36b35093c77djet";//api key is fake at the moment
    $state_ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($state_ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($state_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($state_ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $state_result = curl_exec ($state_ch);
    $state_result = json_decode($state_result);
    $debug = 1;
      print_r($state_result);
```

The response is as following

```
{
"accountId": "fjnfd",
"firstName": "first name",
"lastName": "last name",
"email": "xyz.com@gmail.com",
"phone": "+3798798",
"companyName": "",
"state": "state address",
"city": "city address",
"street": "street address",
"zipCode": "226010",
"countryCode": {
  "countryCodeId": "100",
  "countryCode": "IN"
},
"industryTag": {
  "industryTagId": null
},
"numberOfEmployees": null,
"timeFormat": "12h",
"timeZone": {
  "name": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "offset": "+09:30"
},
"href": "https://api.getresponse.com/v3/accounts"
}
```

I am not getting how to save the data tried ***GetResponseAPI3.class.php*** from Github but it's not happening.

get response documentation

Links that can Help

[Authentication](https://apidocs.getresponse.com/v3)

[Saving contacts](https://apidocs.getresponse.com/v3/resources/contacts#contacts.create)

You may vote it down but I have been trying for last 3 days and it's not happening.

Comment: Eggzacklee the same experience. Updating contact is NOT WORKING.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you don't need to send a request to `https://api.getresponse.com/v3/accounts` to authenticate your calls. The data that you receive means your authentication headers are probably correct, so can directly proceed to sending POST requests to `https://api.getresponse.com/v3/contacts`. Your payload looks fine so you should make it successfully.